# Every point in completion of a topological group in closure of a countable subset

Tags: general-topology, abelian-groups, topological-groups

Is there a name or perhaps some interesting equivalent condition for the following condition on an abelian topological group $G$ with uniformity generated by the neighbourhoods of 0?

> Every point in the completion of $G$ is in the closure of a countable subset of $G$ (note: not necessarily the same countable subset for every point)

(Not assuming $G$ is metrizable)

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is metrizable?

Comment: What is your definition of "the completion" of $G$?

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is first-countable, then the definition of $\hat{G}$ can be made by Cauchy sequences, and the result is immediate. In the case when $G$ is not first countable, the definition of the completion is more difficult to work with and I don't see the proof immediately, but I would be surprised if the property you are interested in held in the non-first-countable case.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a characterization in terms of a property of $G$. Are you saying that the completion of $G$ referred to in the question has this property if and only if $G$ is first-countable?

Comment: Edited - I had misread the question, thank you for your correction.

Comment: If G is itself complete and not first-countable, then the condition is satisfied. Yes, I'm hoping for a characterization, or a reference to some discussion